# Render Apex Page Message Only Once inside Apex Repeat

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have an Apex:Repeat at the very top level and inside that depending on the data, I am showing either drop down or checkbox. Now I would like to display apex:pageMessage inside apex:repeat, but since it is inside apex:repeat it is getting displayed multiple times. Is there any way to restrict rendering apex:pageMessage only once inside repeat block? Thanks.

Comment: You need to use apex:variable to manage the display of page message. Set a counter and increase count in loop and when count is 1, display the message

Answer (score 0):

I haven't styled the components, but this is my take.

You can use apex:variable as suggested by Santanu, I created 2 maps 1 to identify the contact that has error, and the other for putting in custom error message(You can make it one map and check if map's contact does not have a error message too and play with the code as needed)

```
<apex:page controller="repeatcontorller">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:repeat value="{!Accountlist}" var="acc">
account:{!acc.name} <br/>
    <apex:repeat value="{!acc.contacts}" var="con">
        <apex:pagemessage rendered="{!IF(errormap[con.id],true,false)}" severity="error" summary="{!errormessage[con.id]}"></apex:pagemessage>
        contact: {!con.name}<br/>
    </apex:repeat><br/><br/>
</apex:repeat> 

</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

controller:

```
public class repeatcontorller {

public list<account> Accountlist{get;set;}
public map<id,boolean> errormap{get;set;}
public map<id,string> errormessage{get;set;}

    public repeatcontorller (){
    errormap = new map<id,boolean>();
    errormessage = new map<id,string>();
        Accountlist =[select id,name,(select id,name from contacts) from account limit 10];
        for(account a:accountlist){
            for(contact c:a.contacts){
                if(c.name.contains('test')){
                    errormap.put(c.id,true); 
                    errormessage.put(c.id,'contact cannot contain name test'+String.valueof(c.id));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output:

[image]